# Where is the journal stored?

Tags: filesystem

I was reading trough the link on [journaling-filesystems](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-journaling-filesystems/) and i would like to know where exactly is the journal stored in my Harddisk.

Some pointers on this image  shown below
[image]

Thanks,
Sen

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The journal is stored in a separate space of the partition, you cannot access it directly. You can use `sudo debugfs /dev/sda#` where the `#` symbol is the number of your partition, and then using `logdump` in `debugfs` to print it out. The output is confusing though.

Generally, as a regular user, you don't need to know about the journal. Using `ext3/4` will be sufficient to prevent data loss (in most cases).

This link might help: http://www.linuxforums.org/forum/red-hat-fedora-linux/121074-ext3-journal.html

Comment: I just wanted to know, as it was stated in the link, what is this on-disk journal? Where is it in the HDD? That picture was a bit confusing to me.

Answer (score 13):

There is no fixed place for the journal; each filesystem stores it in a different place.

If you are expecting it to be a regular file, then you are mistaken; it's more like a part of the filesystem structure like the inode table. The funny point is that ext3/4 treats it exactly like a regular file. It is usually found in the inode number 8, but this is a kernel parameter that can be changed at compile time.

If you want to get technical, [this article by Carlo Wood](https://carlowood.github.io/howto/undelete_ext3.html), written in March 2008, is a great read about the ext3 structure.

If you don't mind put *journal* in a place with words like *partition table*, *inode*, or *block*, and don't worry about it.

Comment: Good comment.. would like to vote up but lack of points.. :-)

Comment: "It is usually found in the inode number 8", can you explain briefly on this to me?

Comment: yup.. i found it.. it is the inode number of the Journal file..

Comment: An inode is the record for an item in the filesystem, which could mean a file, a directory, a symbolic link, or something internal that the user doesn't need to know about - in this case the journal is an inode in ext3/4 (this is not necessarily the case in other filesystems). The inode record is referred to be a unique number.  The inode record does not store the file's data itself - or specific metadata such as the filename, but points to such data.